# StackBuilder is not recognizing PostgreSQL installation

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgagent

I'm trying to install pgagent from stackbuilder for my psql installation. However as you can see the installation is not showing up and I can't manage to find why.

I've reinstalled stackbuilder, the environment variables and path are also set up for psql bin, port 5432 is correctly set up in the firewall...
Has anyone run into this issue and could help me?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same problem! If you resolve it do let us know!

Comment: Here is the source code of the stack builder and that first page of the wizard. It seems like its reading some keys from the registry. I have added some of the keys and values in the registry, but still no lock. Not too fluent with c++, so might would have missed something.. 
https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/stackbuilder/blob/master/IntroductionPage.cpp#L136

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-install PostgreSQL database along with Stackbuilder. That fixed the issue with the listing of the local installation.

Now that it lists, checking the registry shows the following entries:
for:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Services\postgresql-x64-15

[image: Registry entries for stackbuilder]